# Cauchy integral equation with derivative

Tags: integral-equations, singular-integrals

Does anybody know the solution of this singular Cauchy-like integral equation:

$$
y(x) = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}  \frac{y'(x')}{x-x'}dx'\\ 
y(0) = 1, \lim_{ \lvert x \rvert \to \infty } y(x)= 0
$$

The nominator of the integrand is the derivative of the function in the LHS. The function y(x) is symmetric, i.e., y(x) = y(-x). It monotonically decays from 1 to 0 like an exponent as x grows.

If the exact solution does not exist, any guess how to get a good approximation?

## Motivation

I am solving a problem of fluid inflow to a straight slot in an infinite 2D medium. The equations become integral ones because of construction. I am deriving them considering first a point-source problem, and then integrating it over slot dimensions. As a result, I get two equations: for fluid pressure $p$ and inflow $u$:
$$
\beta p''(x) = u(x)\\
p = \int_{-1}^{1}  u(x') ln|x-x'| dx'\\ 
p(0) = 1,  p'(\pm 1) = 0
$$

Here p(x) is symmetric, and u(x) is antisymmetric with respect to x=0.

In the limiting case of small $\beta$ (which means small conductivity of a slot), I turn to infinite boundaries, take integration by parts, and write the equation above for the pressure only, where y(x) = p(x).

## My efforts

Meanwhile, I was managed to solve this equation only numerically. I want to know if the analytical solution exists.

Thank you very much.

Comment: Dimitry, what have you tried? Could write your efforts and attempts in your post?

Comment: Angelo, this equation comes from physics of fluid inflow to a fracture. In the limiting case, I have managed to reduce more complex equations to this simple equation, and hoped to find an accurate solution, but could not.

Comment: Dimitry, you should write it in your post, not here as a comment, moreover you should add more context if you want us to help you. Read [this thread](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question) in order to learn how to ask a good question on this site.

Comment: Alright. I'll modify my post. Thank you.

Comment: Your equation for $y$ is equivalent to $y=\pi  H(y')$, where $H$ is the Hilbert transform on $\mathbb R$. Taking Fourier transform gives that $\hat y(\xi)=-i\pi\operatorname{sgn}(\xi)\widehat{y'}(\xi)=2\pi^2\xi\operatorname{sgn}(\xi)\hat y(\xi).$  You require the exponential decay of $y$, so $\hat y\in L^2$, hence $\hat y=0$ and $y=0$. It seems strange... Maybe I made mistakes somewhere...